# Extracting centroids of clusters as examples in RapidMiner?

Tags: cluster-analysis, k-means, rapidminer, centroid

I have a big amount of data that has 4 attributes and its respective label. I am applying a K-Means cluster block in order to create 3 clusters of the data (I want to get Low level, Mid Level and High Level data).

I am plotting this data in an Advanced Chart. Of course I can use the cluster attribute as a dimension (colour for example) in order to identify to which cluster the data belongs, but I want to have only one point for each cluster (the centroid).

So the defined question is: After the clustering..**How can I extract the centroids as examples?**, so I just have 3 points of data and not 1000 for example.

Answer (score 1):

There is an operator for this called `Extract Cluster Prototypes`.